# How do I display the P and global R from Simper() in R?

Tags: r, vegan

I'm using a simper analysis and need to see the P and Global R2 values.

I see that P is calculated by `simper()`, but cannot get it do display.

How do I display the P and the Global R2 for this analysis? I'm not seeing an option for this in the documentation...

Code example:

```
library(vegan) 
data(dune) 
data(dune.env)
sim <- simper(dune, dune.env$Management)
summary(sim, ordered = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing is that you must calculate the *p*-values (and read the warning about them in `?simper`): set `permutations`  to some value like suggested in the manual. With your example, for instance,

```
sim <- simper(dune, dune.env$Management, permutations=999)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Field work took over for a while there. Thank you for the suggestion, that worked well for the P. When I read papers displaying Simper tables they're always accompanied by a Global R2, but I'm failing to see where this comes from. Best I can figure is it's actually an ANOSIM r2...
Also, I agree with the warning (but the committee gets what the committee wants)